# wicked pdf rendering css / javascript in Ruby

Tags: ruby, wicked-pdf

I'm trying to convert html page with wicked pdf but the  html / css / javascript are not displayed.

Here is my controller :

```
respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.pdf do
            render :pdf => 'rapport_pdf',
          :template => 'messages/template_load_pdf.pdf.erb',
          :layout => 'rapport_load_pdf.html.erb',
          :show_as_html => params[:debug].present?
        end
    end
```

Here is my rapport_load_pdf.html.erb :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>PDF</title>
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "application" -%>
</head>
<body>
<div class='container'>
<%= yield %>
</div>
</body>
```

Here is my gemfile :

```
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried with `wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track": true`

Comment: Check [format of options](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#advanced-usage-with-all-available-options).

Comment: Thanks for your help Snoobie, i tried but it did not work. I added the debug parameters in the URL and it was good. Actually I can see html / css / javascript. I still have a problem now with boostrap / some font-family and font awesome, in my console, Chrome tell me that there are not allowed to load local ressource. Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried different techniques to speedup my pdf generation. But these steps were pretty helpful.

1. Try using [font-awesome-rails](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails) and [bootstrap ruby gem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem)
2. Use separate `scss` file to import necessary css/scss files. And, Try to avoid importing unnecessary css files. (Because loading external css files and images kills the server memory and delay the pdf process.)

Please see the sample code below
[image]

3. Import your stylesheet in the pdf layout file as bellow.

`<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "pdf_layout", media: "all" -%>`

Please check more details [here](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf)